# Regular Expression Local Path File Validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

The following regular expression is used to validate a local drive path.

```
(^(?:[a-zA-Z]:|(\\\\|\/\/)[\w\.]+(\\|\/)[\w.$]+)((\\|\/)|(\\\\|\/\/))(?:[\w ]+(\\|\/))*\w([\w. ])+$)
```

http://regexr.com/3bm2i

The problem is that it allows the following:

```
Z:\daily\Test
Z:\daily\Test.d ocx
```

The regular expression should require a dot after the last slash and also not allow space in the file extension (i.e) after the last dot.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex does the tricks:

```
(^(?:[a-zA-Z]:|(\\\\|\/\/)[\w\.]+(\\|\/)[\w.$]+)((\\|\/)|(\\\\|\/\/))(?:[\w ]+(\\|\/))*\w([\w. ])+[\.][a-zA-Z]+$)
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't recommend using regex for this as the path depends on the filesystem on which it would be used.

You should instead make some basic checks only, and handle exceptions if any.

A regex as simple as below would suffice:

```
[.][^\ .]+$ //would check if the path has extention
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(^(?:[a-zA-Z]:|(\\\\|\/\/)[\w\.]+(\\|\/)[\w.$]+)((\\|\/)|(\\\\|\/\/))(?:[\w ]+(\\|\/))*\w([\w.])+\.\w+$)
```